# States List: Foreach Loop

Tags: c#, .net, list, foreach

I have adapted some code that generates a random state value (below)

```
public static string GenRandomState()
{
    List<string> lst = new List<string>();
    randomState = string.Empty;
    lst.Add("Alabama");
    lst.Add("Alaska");
    lst.Add("Arizona");
    ...
    randomState = lst.OrderBy(xx => rnd.Next()).First();
    return randomState;
} // End GenRandomState
```

I would like to remove the randomization and, instead, have the method call the states in the same order (Top to Bottom) each time the method is called.

So, what I'd like to see is this: each iteration, a state value (starting at the top) will be retrieved. The execution will continue until all the state values have been called. I think a Foreach loop would be appropriate but I am not sure how best to implement.

Comment: If you want to call one state (a different one) every time you call the function, you would have to declare the involved variables (at least, the index of the current state, the one which is being modified) outside the function. This is very basic and consequently off-topic here.

Comment: @varocarbas, why would that be considered off-topic? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @DangerZone This is my personal opinion, but I consider it off-topic because of being extremely basic; like asking the differences between `string` and `int` or what a function is. The solution (= declaring the given variables within the right context, in this case, outside the given function) is straightforward and thus doesn’t provide worthy-knowledge to anyone else (with minimum programming understanding); determining what the solution might be (= analysing a very simple algorithm and coming up with the most adequate approach) is also level-0 of debugging...

Comment: @DangerZone ... On the other hand, if this question/answer has been helpful to you (or to anyone you know or you think that might be helpful to other people), you might consider it on-topic and act accordingly (= don't vote to put it on hold as off-topic, in case you have enough reputation what doesn't seem the case, neither say that it is off-topic). If you were in such a situation, I would recommend you to do some heavy learning (not in C# but in general programming/algorithm building) because this is definitively way too basic.

Comment: I see what you mean now @varocarbas. I guess it all depends on your point of view. I agree it's a little too basic.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are leaving the loop and only selecting one state each call I would not use a `foreach` loop and instead keep a index variable and use that to choose which index you are going to use.

First, I would move the creation of the list outside of the function so it is only done once.

```
public class StateInfo
{
    static StateInfo()
    {
        lst.Add("Alabama");
        lst.Add("Alaska");
        lst.Add("Arizona");
        ...
    }

    static readonly List<string> _lst = new List<string>();
    static readonly object _listLock = new object();
    static int _nextIndex = 0;

    public static string GetNextState()
    {
        int i = 0;
        lock(_listLock)
        {
            i = _nextIndex;
            _nextIndex = (_nextIndex + 1) % _lst.Count;                
        }
        return _lst[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: How caller can determine that it has reached the end of list?

Comment: My implmentation has no end, it repeats, restarting from the begining.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the function to return an `IEnumerable`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var s in GetStates())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<string> GetStates()
{
    var lst = new List<string>();
    lst.Add("Alabama");
    lst.Add("Alaska");
    lst.Add("Arizona");
    ...
    return lst;
}
```